# String.format to get the output date in dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm pattern (Java)

Tags: java

```
String.format(start.toString("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"));
```

where start is a date input in `LocalDateTime` class from `org.joda.time` api

when i am using this code, its returning month like this "Dec" but i want the output as "DEC".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific case, I would use `.toUpperCase()`

Comment: but when i have defined the pattern as "MMM" then why it is not returning month in all capital letters.

Comment: Capital `M` means Month and lower case `m` means minutes.  Can you say in the documentation which states you should be getting upper case months?

Answer (score 1):

If this (String.format(start.toString("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"));) retrieves the correct format of what you want, then you can simply use

**String.format(start.toString("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm")).toUpperCase();**

Answer (score 1):

I always using substring, in my case like this :

```
String sDate = String.format(start.toString("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm"));
String oDate = sDate.substring(0, 2)+"-"+sDate.substring(3, 6).toUppercase()+"-"+sDate.substring(7, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way will be to replace a substring by the uppercase version.

```
Date start = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat oFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm");
String sDate = oFormat.format(start);

System.out.println(sDate);

sDate = sDate.substring(0,3) + sDate.substring(3,6).toUpperCase() +  sDate.substring(6,sDate.length());

System.out.println(sDate);
```

Comment: Note: its simpler to upper case the whole string.

Comment: Sure it is! :) But wont if there is timezone or something one day. Good to know multiple solutions!